# get div width jquery

Tags: jquery, css, width

I need to show a div (called over) when I go over it with cursor. Over div has position absolute. I did it using jquery. It works good, but the only problem is that over div doesn't get parent div width.
I do it using jquery, this is the code:

```
var count = 0;
$('.resultbox').each(function(){
    $('#main').append('<div class="content" id="t'+count+'"></div>');
    $('#t' + count).append('<div class="over"></div>');

    $('#t'+count).append('<span>some text here</span>');

    $('.asd', this).each(
            $('#t' + count).append('<span>and other text here</span>');
        });
    });
    //alert('');
    $('#t' + count + ' > .over').css('width', $('#t' + count).css('width'));
    $('#t' + count + ' > .over').css('height', $('#t' + count).css('height'));
    count++;
});

$('.content').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.over', this).show();
}); 

$('.content').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.over', this).hide();
});
```

and css is:

```
#main{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #FFF;
z-index: 999;
text-align: left;   
}

.content{
width: auto;
display: inline-block;
margin: 20px;
padding: 5px;
border: 1px solid #000;
clear: both;
}

.content span{
display: inline-block;
}

.over{
position: absolute;
background: url(share.png) #FFF no-repeat center center;
opacity: 0.6;
z-index: 999;
display: none;
}

.over:hover{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

As you can see I put also an alert. If I comment it over div doesn't get his parent width, while if i don't comment it, over div get the right parent width. Why!?

Thanks, Mattia

Comment: can u paste u r html, css and jquery code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I generate the html code using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I smell like your parent element in HTML is not getting loaded when you try to find the width.When you give an alert the parent element loads.Try finding the width of the parent element when you make sure it loads.

Comment: Yes, I also think so. How can I do to get parent width when it is loaded? I try to do this using load function: $('#t' + count).load(function(){get width; }); but it doesn't work.. I get a wrong width.

Comment: Oops I though of suggesting you to use load().May be try ready function like this 

        $(document).ready(function()
     {
       //YOUR CODE
     });